# How to maintain CSS styles while printing from a specific part of a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to print a specific part of my page and also maintain its style. currently when I press print all my CSS styles are stripped away. Here is my HTML document.

```js
const button = document.createElement('button') //this is the print button
button.classList.add('printButton')
button.textContent = 'Print'

const entryContainer = document.getElementById('container')
const card = document.createElement('div') //this will be the card to print
card.classList.add('card')
card.setAttribute('id', 'printcard')
card.textContent = 'I failed the first quarter of a class in middle school, so I made a fake report card. I did this every quarter that year. I forgot that they mail home the end-of-year cards, and my mom got it before I could intercept with my fake. She was PISSED—at the school for their error. The teacher also retired that year and had already thrown out his records, so they had to take my mother’s “proof” (the fake ones I made throughout the year) and “correct” the “mistake.” I’ve never told her the truth.'

entryContainer.appendChild(card)
entryContainer.appendChild(button)

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //this is the code that actually does the printing
  var prtContent = document.getElementById("printcard");
  var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
  WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
  WinPrint.document.write('<link rel=stylesheet href="style.css">')
  WinPrint.document.close();
  WinPrint.focus();
  WinPrint.print();
  WinPrint.close();
})
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 500px;
  list-style: none;
  gap: 10px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(8, 8, 8);
}

.card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: red !important;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(8, 8, 8);
}

.printButton {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This is</li>
  <li>The content that </li>
  <li>I dont want </li>
  <li>printed</li>
  <li>on the page</li>
</ul>
<div class="card-container" id="container"></div>
```

help me with pointers on what I need to do.
the iamge i get is[image]

This is the image result that i get, the expected result should be like this one except only the text and its border and color are visible, all else are blank
[image]

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser's devtools console? [Incidentally, your snippet cannot work in this SO environment because of the sandboxing'.

Comment: There are no errors

Comment: When you write the innerHTML of the element that you want to print you are writing only its content (which is just the text). There is no element to style. [There will also be other problems, in particular that the window get closed before the style has had time to load].

Comment: How would I write the elements and text together

Answer (score 1):

try that --> add a `no-Print` class:
**CSS**

```css
@media print { 
  .no-Print { display : none; }
  }
```

**HTML**

```HTML
<ul class="no-Print">
  <li>This is</li>
  <li>The content that </li>
  <li>I dont want </li>
  <li>printed</li>
  <li>on the page</li>
</ul>
<div class="card-container" id="container">
   blah bla blah
</div>
```

**old method :**
HTML

```HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
...

<style media="print">
  .no-Print { display : none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <ul class="no-Print">
    <li>This is</li>
    <li>The content that </li>
    <li>I dont want </li>
    <li>printed</li>
    <li>on the page</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="card-container" id="container">
     blah bla blah
  </div>

...
```

Comment: its not working, also in my example the **<ul>** is not visible by default

Comment: @deniskiplangat  strange, I just tested it with success (FireFox).    Otherwise I made an update to show the old method

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the answer, in the old code I had put all these lines in javascript alot of it being unnecessary, here is the old code.

```
const button = document.createElement('button') //this is the print button
button.classList.add('printButton')
button.textContent = 'Print'

const entryContainer = document.getElementById('container')
const card = document.createElement('div') //this will be the card to print
card.classList.add('card')
card.setAttribute('id', 'printcard')
card.textContent = 'I failed the first quarter of a class in middle school, so I made a fake report card. I did this every quarter that year. I forgot that they mail home the end-of-year cards, and my mom got it before I could intercept with my fake. She was PISSED—at the school for their error. The teacher also retired that year and had already thrown out his records, so they had to take my mother’s “proof” (the fake ones I made throughout the year) and “correct” the “mistake.” I’ve never told her the truth.'

entryContainer.appendChild(card)
entryContainer.appendChild(button)

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //this is the code that actually does the printing
  var prtContent = document.getElementById("printcard");
  var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
  WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
  WinPrint.document.write('<link rel=stylesheet href="style.css">')
  WinPrint.document.close();
  WinPrint.focus();
  WinPrint.print();
  WinPrint.close();
})
```

here is the new code that works as required

```
const button = document.createElement('button')  //this is the print button
button.classList.add('printButton')
button.textContent = 'Print'

const entryContainer = document.getElementById('container')
const card = document.createElement('div') //this will be the card to print
card.classList.add('card')
card.classList.add('card', 'print');
card.setAttribute('id','printcard')
card.textContent = 'I failed the first quarter of a class in middle school, so I made a fake report card. I did this every quarter that year. I forgot that they mail home the end-of-year cards, and my mom got it before I could intercept with my fake. She was PISSED—at the school for their error. The teacher also retired that year and had already thrown out his records, so they had to take my mother’s “proof” (the fake ones I made throughout the year) and “correct” the “mistake.” I’ve never told her the truth.'




entryContainer.appendChild(card)
entryContainer.appendChild(button)

button.addEventListener('click',()=>{

    //this is the code that actually does the printing
    var prtContent = document.getElementById("printcard");
    print(prtContent)

})
```